# Subset according to their label

Tags: python, numpy, zip, list-comprehension

Suppose I have two lists: `letters = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]` and `digits = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0]`. I would like the final result to be `output = [[a, f, i], [b, c, e, i], [d, g, h]]`.

Here `0`, `1` and `2` are just different classes. For instance,`a` is from class `0` while `b` and `c` are from class `1`. I just need to put the letters in a sublist according to their class.

I think I can you `zip()` here and a list comprehension, but I am not sure how to do that. How can I do that using numpy?

Comment: Can you explain how did you get the desired `output`?

Comment: Here `0`, `1` and `2` are just different classes. For instance,`a` is from class `0` while `b` and `c` are from class `1`. I just need to put the letters in a sublist according to their class. I need to have a general implementation because the number of classes can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` and temporary dictionary:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
digits = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0]

tmp = {}
for d, l in zip(digits, letters):
    tmp.setdefault(d, []).append(l)

out = []
for k in sorted(tmp):
    out.append(tmp[k])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['a', 'f'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'i'], ['d', 'g', 'h']]
```

---

Or: Another version (using `itertools.groupby`):

```
from itertools import groupby

out = []
for _, g in groupby(sorted(zip(digits, letters)), lambda k: k[0]):
    out.append([l for _, l in g])

print(out)
```

Comment: You can probably using `tmp.values()` here instead

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` solution is also possible:

```
digits = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0])
letters = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'])
argidx = np.argsort(digits)
digits, letters = digits[argidx], letters[argidx]
markers = np.diff(digits, prepend=digits[0])
marker_idx, = np.nonzero(markers)
np.split(letters, marker_idx)
```

Output:

```
[array(['a', 'f', 'i'], dtype='<U1'), array(['b', 'c', 'e'], dtype='<U1'), array(['d', 'g', 'h'], dtype='<U1')]
```

Comment: Rather than `prepend` to the `diff`, which reallocates memory, you may want to add 1 to `marker_idx`. Also, `flatnonzero` is easier than `nonzero` here. +1 for a proper numpy solution. Ignore the nitpicking

Comment: @Mad Physicist I've seen `prepend` is unpopular but didn't expect it to be inefficient in memory. These were a good hints.

Comment: `prepend` calls `np.concatenate` in the pure python portion of the code. It's pretty ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged numpy (I personally prefer pandas groupby since it is clean and meant for this purpose):

```
d,l = list(zip(*(sorted(zip(digits,letters)))))
d = np.array(d)
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, d[:-1] != d[1:], True])
output = [list(l[i:j]) for i,j in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])]
#[['a', 'f'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'i'], ['d', 'g', 'h']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on the answer (here with `groupby` and `itemgetter`):

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
digits = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0]

combined_letters_digits = sorted(zip(letters, digits), key=itemgetter(1))
letter_groups = groupby(combined_letters_digits, itemgetter(1))
out = [[item[0] for item in group_data] for (key, group_data) in letter_groups]

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

much more concise, no loops with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
    index=[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1],
    name='letters'
)

[*s.groupby(level=0).agg(list)]


[['a', 'f'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'i'], ['d', 'g', 'h']]
```